# Maximum travel duration to Kazakhstan without visa for US citizens

Tags: visas, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, kazakhstan

There seems to be a difference between duration of visa free travel on usembassy.gov and Embassy of Kazakhstan in US websites:

https://kz.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/visa-free-travel-kazakhstan/

> The pilot visa free program was extended till December 31, 2017. The program allows all short-term U.S. citizen travelers to visit Kazakhstan without a visa for up to 15 calendar days from the moment of border crossing for all purposes of travel excluding employment and missionary work.

http://www.kazakhembus.com/Kazakhstan-visa-information

> I'm a U.S. citizen: do I need a visa?
>   U.S. citizens traveling to Kazakhstan for fewer than 30 days do not need a visa to enter the country.

1. What is the real duration of visa free stay in Kazakhstan for US citizens?
2. Has anyone had recent experience staying without visa for longer than 15 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 30 days, as stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=us&DE=kz&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of USA for a maximum stay
>   of 30 days.

Used to be 15 days, but got more generous at the start of 2017.